# How to optimize a factor counting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I've been asked to sum the factors other than 1 and the number itself of every number in an array. The problem is it must be able to handle very large arrays with very large numbers and my current implementation takes very long for arrays of size 100,000,000. My code for counting each numbers factors is

```
static long countFactors(long num){
    long count=0;
    long max =(long) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
    for(int i=2; i<=max;i++){
        if(num%i==0&&(i*i)!=num){
            // count i and n/i as a factor
            count+=2;
            if(num/i<max){
                max=num/i;
            }
        }            
        else if(num%i==0){
            // just add one factor since it is the numbers root.
            count+=1;

        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Does anybody have any optimisation suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, don't do it.  Factoring large composite numbers is a known NP problem (or at least strongly theorized to be NP), meaning the best you can do is exponential time.  If you still want to do it, look up factorization algorithms.  None of them are faster than exponential, but some are reasonably fast.

Comment: Request for clarification - Are you supposed to sum all factors, or just the prime factors?  For instance, for 12 the possible factors are 2, 3, 4, and 6, but the prime factors are 2 & 3.  Also, are you summing for each number in the array individually, or creating a grand sum across the array?

Comment: Note in your code you're not actually summing the factors, you're counting the factors. This is very different, please change your code or your description so they match.

Comment: @pjs I'm assuming all considering he says, "and the number itself". You wouldn't ALSO count/sum the number itself if you were looking only for prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting the best idea at the beginning of this post:

**A number divisible by `n` is divisible by all the factors of `n`.**

Maybe that is the key to reducing your time complexity. Now the rest:

Right now you perform the test `(i*i)!=num` O(max) times when it only need be done once. (`for(int i=2; i**<**max;i++)` then check the square root). You did say very large numbers so this could save a little bit.

Also what is this?    `if(num/i<max){
                max=num/i;
            }` If I am reading correctly, this is superfluous. It never happens that a factor `i` in this loop is greater than square root of `num`.

Finally, space permitting, you could make the outside loop over `i` put the loop through the array on the inside. This would save a tiny bit by not needing to repeat `i*i`. These are just micro optimizations on your current algorithm.

Comment: It suggests that you could start at root of the largest `num` and find its largest factor pair `a*b = num`. Then the factors of `num` are all those of `a` and `b`, `a`, and `b`, `1` and `num`, though at some point you must count repeats. Storing for reuse the factorization for, say, the first few million integers is easy. Instead of starting at root `num`, start at the end of this list.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer this question because it is hard to know exactly what the question is. Some comments follow. If the question is clarified I might be able to give a better answer.

1) It is not clear if you want the distinct prime factors of a number *n*, the prime factors with their multiplicities, or the divisors of a number. For instance, given the number *n* = 12, the distinct prime factors are 2 and 3, the prime factors with their multiplicities are 2, 2 and 3, and the divisors are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 12. Your program answers the question about divisors, so I assume that is what you want, but you also mention that you want to eliminate both 1 and *n* from the list, which is unusual.

2) At various times you mention both the *count* of the factors and the *sum* of the factors. Please clarify exactly what you want.

3) It is not clear if you are dealing with arrays of length 10^8 or with *n* as large as 10^8. If your array has length 10^8 then whatever you do is going to take a while. If you have a much smaller array, say a thousand numbers *n*, each less than 10^8, this becomes a lot simpler.

Assuming that you want divisors, here's a function that takes the factors of *n* with their multiplicities and returns both the sum and count of the divisors of *n*; if you want, you can subtract 2 from the count and *n*+1 from the sum to exclude 1 and *n*:

```
function divSumCount(n)
    mult, sum, count, prev := 2, 1, 1, 0
    for fact in sort(factors(n))
        if fact == prev
            mult := mult + 1
        else if prev <> 0
            sum := sum * (prev ** mult - 1) / (prev - 1)
            count := count * mult
            mult := 2
        prev := fact
    sum := sum * (prev ** mult - 1) / (prev - 1)
    count := count * mult
    return sum, count
```

This is pseudocode, which I will leave to you to translate to Java. Assuming that *n* is not larger than 10^8, here is a simple program that factors *n* using trial division, returning the factors sorted in increasing order; if *n* is larger, you will want a better algorithm to find its factors:

```
function factors(n)
    f, fs := 3, []
    while n % 2 == 0
        append 2 to fs
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            append f to fs
            n := n / f
        f := f + 2
    if n > 1 append n to fs
    return fs
```

4) If the numbers *n* are contiguous in an array, say from 54813000 to 54823000, you can sieve for the factors instead of laboriously factoring each *n*, which would be much faster.

Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT EMPTOR: This is an idea that I have not checked with benchmark, so it may not be a good solution.

For a single number your code is pretty good. But if you have to find the factors of lots of numbers, maybe finding the prime factors is a good solutions.

My idea would be like this

1) Find the biggest number from the list that you have to process (max).

2) Find the prime numbers between 1 and max/2 (this is the hard part, but is done only once).

3) You decompose each number in prime factors, v.g. 150 is 2*3*5*5

4) All the factor are combinations of the prime factors, in this case they are

*) 2

*) 2*3 = 6

*) 2*5 = 10

*) 2*3*5 = 30

*) 2*5^2 = 50

*) 3

*) 3*5 = 15

*) 3*5^2 = 75

*) 5

*) 5^2 = 25

The advantages are that you only check for primes, which are only a proportion of the numbers (and, if your number get bigger, a decreasing one). The disavantage is the final step of calculating the non-prime factors, and the time (and memory) to calculate the primes (although you may have them precalculated and stored in a file to a certain size).

Comment: Nice Idea. The number of comibnations of the prime factors for 150 = power(2,4) - 1 - power(2,2) = 11. (5 occurs twice). I think you missed out 5, 25 and 150 as the factors.

Comment: I would also suggest to first scan the array and check if any number is a factor of another.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Added `5` and `25`, thanks (as per the enunciate, 150 must not be considered), and the formula is a nice addendum. As per the test for divisibility, I am not sure it would be useful, as it will be a complexity of `n^2` (with `n` as big as `100.000.000`) and it is not clear how many numbers you would simplify with it.

Answer (score 0):

I may regret this, but I'm gonna give this a shot.  I'll assume that you have plenty of RAM/swap available, and are more worried about the computation time.  I'm also assuming you really want the prime factors, not all factors.

The first thing I'd do is sort your array and identify the unique values.  I would then try constructing a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) using an array `sieve` to identify all primes up to the square root of the maximum value in your (sorted) unique values array.  I would also keep a parallel array of all numbers up to the maximum, call it `sum_array`, and initialize it to all zeros. As I stepped through the `sieve` array to mask all multiples of the current value, I'd also step through `sum_array` at the same indices and add the current prime to the running total for each element in parallel to masking multiples of that prime in the `sieve` array.

Since I don't really know what this is for, I've run out of suggestions for what to do beyond this.